# Failed to connect Oracle11g using c# code locally

Tags: .net, oracle

I have a Oracle11g enterprise installed in Windows 2016 server.
The IP address is:192.168.2.112

```
using System;
 using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
namespace OracleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.2.112:1521/ORCL;User Id=system;Password=Password1;";
            con.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

I run the code on the Oracle server. It runs into following error.
[image]

If I replaced the IP '192.168.2.112' with '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost'. 
It works.
The c:\windows\system32\drivers\hosts file is empty. no customized entries.

Listner.ora file:

```
 SID_LIST_LISTENER =
      (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
          (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
        )
      )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator
```

Comment: Please don't paste images. Provide code and error messages as formatted text (in cmd console hint ENTER to copy selected text to clipboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `localhost` to ip address  `192.168.2.112` in `listener.ora` and restart service `OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener`.

```
 SID_LIST_LISTENER =
      (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (PROGRAM = extproc)
          (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
        )
      )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.112)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator
```

For diagnostics, run the `lsnrctl` utility and see that the address is listed in the 
Listening Endpoints Summary section.

```
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xxx.yyy.zzz)(PORT=1521)))

D:\>lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 05-DEC-2019 08:19:48

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                05-NOV-2019 07:19:36
Uptime                    30 days 1 hr. 0 min. 17 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\oradba\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\app\oradba\diag\tnslsnr\xxx.yyy.zzz\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xxx.yyy.zzz)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "r88.rrr.zzz.ddd" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "r88", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "r88XDB.rrr.zzz.ddd" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "r88", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL>
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the IP entry to the 'listener.ora' file resolves the issue. I randomly run into this issue in some of the service. Looks like if the IP Address on the machine is fixed, I don't even need to modify the listener.ora. However, If the IP Address is dynamic assigned byDHCP, i need to add the entry...

Answer (score 0):

If this happens always, it literally means that the machine exists but that it has no services listening on the specified port, or there is a firewall stopping you.

just try to telnet to port 192.168.2.112:1521 using windows command and make sure port is listening.

telnet 192.168.2.112:1521

Comment: netstat -aon |findstr 1521 shows that only 127.0.0.1 has the port opening.